# Grid Event RightTapped not always occurring

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Well, my problem is that I don't know exactly how it works. In my opinion, the code is simple and it obviously should work, but it doesn't. At least not always. (sometimes it works, but other times it does not).

In my app, I'm trying to add/remove everything dynamically:

```
class Kategoria 
{
    private CheckBox PriceExists { get; set; }
    private TextBox Category { get; set; }
    private StackPanel AddFrame { get; set; }
    private ComboBox InOrOut { get; set; }
    private Button Add { get; set; }
    private TextBox Price { get; set; }
    private StackPanel MainFrame { get; set; }
    public List<Option> Categories { get; set; }
    private GridView CategoriesFrame { get; set; }
    private List<Grid> CategoriesCollection { get; set; }

    public Kategoria(string kategoria, string kwota)
    {
    }

    public Kategoria()
    {
        TextBlock _title1 = new TextBlock();
        TextBlock _title2 = new TextBlock();
        InOrOut = new ComboBox();
        PriceExists = new CheckBox();
        Category = new TextBox();
        AddFrame = new StackPanel();
        Add = new Button();
        Price = new TextBox();
        MainFrame = new StackPanel();
        Categories = new List<Option>();
        CategoriesFrame = new GridView();
        CategoriesCollection = new List<Grid>();

        InOrOut.Items.Add("Wydatki");
        InOrOut.Items.Add("Dochody");            
        _title1.Text = "Dodaj kategorię";
        _title2.Text = "Aktywne kategorię";

        PriceExists.Content = "Stała kwota?";
        Category.Text = "Nazwa kategorii";
        Add.Content = "Dodaj";
        Price.Text = "Miesięczna kwota";

        _title1.FontSize = 50;
        _title2.FontSize = 50;

        InOrOut.SelectedIndex = 0;
        InOrOut.Height = Category.Height;
        InOrOut.Width = 110;
        InOrOut.Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(10);
        PriceExists.Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(10);

        Category.Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(10);
        Category.MaxLength = 18;

        Price.Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(10);
        Price.MaxLength = 6;

        CategoriesFrame.Background = new 
          Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(21,154,134,23));
        CategoriesFrame.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        CategoriesFrame.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        CategoriesFrame.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;
        CategoriesFrame.Height = 380;
        CategoriesFrame.Width = 900;

        PriceExists.Checked+=Kw_Checked;
        PriceExists.Unchecked+=Kw_Unchecked;
        Category.GotFocus += Kat_Tapped;
        Price.GotFocus += Kwota_Tapped;

        Add.Click += Add_Click;
        AddFrame.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        MainFrame.Width = 1000;
        CategoriesFrame.Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10);
        MainFrame.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        MainFrame.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        MainFrame.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Top;

        AddFrame.Children.Add(PriceExists);
        AddFrame.Children.Add(InOrOut);
        AddFrame.Children.Add(Category);
        AddFrame.Children.Add(Add);

        MainFrame.Children.Add(_title1);
        MainFrame.Children.Add(AddFrame);
        MainFrame.Children.Add(_title2);
        MainFrame.Children.Add(CategoriesFrame);

        FillGrids();
    }

    private void AddGrid()
    {
        Grid Div = new Grid();
        CheckBox new_Cat = new CheckBox();

        if (PriceExists.IsChecked==true)
            new_Cat.Content = "["+InOrOut.SelectedItem.ToString()+"] "+Category.Text+"
              "+Price.Text+"zł";
        else
            new_Cat.Content = "[" + InOrOut.SelectedItem.ToString() + "] " + Category.Text + "
               " + "0" + "zł";

        Div.MinWidth = 270;
        Div.RightTapped += Div_RightTapped;
        Div.Children.Add(new_Cat);
        CategoriesCollection.Add(Div);
        CategoriesFrame.Items.Add(Div);

        PriceExists.IsChecked = false;
        Category.Text = "Nazwa kategorii";
    }

    private void Div_RightTapped(object sender,
      Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //problematyczny kod.
        if (CategoriesFrame.SelectedItems.Count == 1 &&
          CategoriesFrame.SelectedItems[0].Equals(sender) )
        {
            MainFrame.Children.Remove(MainFrame.Children.OfType<Button>().First());
        }
        else
        {                
            if (MainFrame.Children.OfType<Button>().SingleOrDefault() == null)
            {
                Button remove = new Button();
                remove.Content = "Usuń zaznaczone kategorię";
                remove.Click += Remove_Click;
                MainFrame.Children.Add(remove);
            }                
        }
    }

    private async void Remove_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CategoriesFrame.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            Categories.RemoveAt(CategoriesCollection.IndexOf
              ((Grid)CategoriesFrame.SelectedItems[0]));
            CategoriesCollection.Remove((Grid)CategoriesFrame.SelectedItems[0]);
            CategoriesFrame.Items.Remove(CategoriesFrame.SelectedItems[0]);

            Remove_Click(this, null);
            await Serialize(); 
        }
        else
        {
            MainFrame.Children.Remove(MainFrame.Children.OfType<Button>().SingleOrDefault());
        }
    }

    private async void FillGrids()
    {
        await Deserialize();

        foreach (Option Opcja in Categories)
        {

            CheckBox Cat_active = new CheckBox();
            Grid Div = new Grid();
            Div.MinWidth = 100;
            Cat_active.Content = "[" + Opcja.InOut + "] " + 
              Opcja.Title + "  " + Opcja.Value + "zł";
            Div.Children.Add(Cat_active);
            Div.RightTapped+=Div_RightTapped;
            CategoriesCollection.Add(Div);        
        }

        foreach (Grid Grd in CategoriesCollection)
        {
            CategoriesFrame.Items.Add(Grd);
        }
    }

    private async void Add_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PriceExists.IsChecked == true)
            Categories.Add(new 
              Option(InOrOut.SelectedItem.ToString(),Category.Text,Price.Text));
        else
            Categories.Add(new Option(InOrOut.SelectedItem.ToString(),Category.Text, "0"));

        await Serialize();
        AddGrid();
    }
    private async Task Serialize()
    {
        using (var stream = await
          ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("Opcje.txt",
            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
        {
            XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Option>));
            using (XmlWriter xml = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }))
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(xml, Categories);
                xml.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task Deserialize()
    {
        using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("Opcje.txt"))
        {
            XmlSerializer Deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Option>));
            using (XmlReader xml = XmlReader.Create(stream))
            {
                Categories = (List<Option>)Deserializer.Deserialize(xml);
                xml.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Kwota_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Price.Text == "Miesięczna kwota")
            Price.Text = "";
    }

    private void Kat_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Category.Text == "Nazwa kategorii")
            Category.Text = "";
    }

    private void Kw_Unchecked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddFrame.Children.Remove(Price);
    }

    private void Kw_Checked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddFrame.Children.Remove(Add);
        AddFrame.Children.Add(Price);
        AddFrame.Children.Add(Add);
    }

    public StackPanel GetHndlr()
    {
        return MainFrame;
    }
}
```

The problem is in this method:

```
 private void Div_RightTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //problematic code
        if (CategoriesFrame.SelectedItems.Count == 1 && CategoriesFrame.SelectedItems[0].Equals(sender) )
        {
            MainFrame.Children.Remove(MainFrame.Children.OfType<Button>().First());
        }
        else
        {                
            if (MainFrame.Children.OfType<Button>().SingleOrDefault() == null)
            {
                Button remove = new Button();
                remove.Content = "Usuń zaznaczone kategorię";
                remove.Click += Remove_Click;
                MainFrame.Children.Add(remove);
            }                
        }
    }
```

Theoretically it should work well and it does (sometimes). Time to time, it's doesn't do what it should do. Simply, when the last item in GridView is unselected, the button is not removed from MainFram(Stackpanel) and sometimes when I'm trying to select one item, button is not added to MainFrame.

I want to know why it is happening so randomly.

Comment: You have posted quite a long piece of code.  You need to provide some explanation of what it is supposed to do.

Comment: All right.... well ... As you can see under the class code is code of the method that makes some problems... well... it should add button to stackpanel(mainframe) if any of GridView(CategoriesFrame) items(Grids) is selected and remove this button if all items are unselected. I made event Righttap couse when u selecting Grid this event occurs but as I said above... this method is good but.... not always... sometimes (i think it's totaly random) it just doesn't work (when it should delete button it doesn't do anything and when it should add button it also doesn't seem to react).